# How to toggle on a feature flag based on a custom context in LaunchDarkly?

Tags: javascript, typescript, launchdarkly

I am trying to figure out how to toggle a feature flag based on a custom context value. However, the LaunchDarkly docs aren't helpful.

I am using https://github.com/launchdarkly/node-server-sdk

An example would be:

I have feature flag that has an option to use `cityContext` or `countryContext` and I want to return `true` if `cityContext` was used as a rule within the feature flag.

I want to understand if the above is possible. As I want to perform custom logic depending on which context is used.

I have tried the following:

```
const cityContext = {
   key: 'uuid',
   custom: {
        city: 'London'
   }
}

const cityValue = await client.variation('any-value', cityContext, false);


const countryContext = {
   key: 'uuid',
   custom: {
        country: 'United Kingdom'
   }
}

const countryValue = await client.variation('any-value', countryContext, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a feature flag in LaunchDarkly
and add a rule that assigns a user some variation based on a context:

- `Control` or `Treatment`
- or simply a boolean value - based on your needs
  [image]

You can add different rules for instance:

1. Rule to serve `Treatment 1` to `city=London`
2. Rule to serve `Treatment 2` to `country=UK`
3. Default rule to serve `Control`